# Why are products that are not linked to a category visible in search results?

Tags: category, products, catalogsearch

In my webshop products that are enabled but not linked to any Category are being displayed in the search result. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: you need to disable those products from backend.

Answer (score 1):

AJ Fast,There are two solution

**1.** Change the `Visibility` of all products to `Catalog`.

**2.** `Disable` the  product  make all products `status ->Disable`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have them on your site at all if you don't want them to be visible?

If you have discontinued products that you want to remove from the front end, you can switch their status to 'disabled'. They will still be searchable in the backend. Or you can delete them completely.